# Query to get rows from a table depending on another column , if all column value exist

Tags: sql

My Table has two columns, no primary key defined.

say name and salary

```
name  salary 
A     100
B     200
B     100
C     100
A     200
```

I want salary of A,B  where fetched salary is not owned by any other name
say distinct salary fetched of A,B is 100,200
But my result will only show 200 as 100 is owned by C

Comment: Tag RDBMS which you are using ? and provide the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure a salary has two different names, and also no other than A and B:

```
select salary
from tablename
group by salary
having count(distinct name) = 2
   and count(case when name not in ('A','B') then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: can you please remove hard coding and rewrite the logic